# While changing to new repo can't start my server after installing npm Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/logurvp/Documents/GitHub/local/populardoctor_webapi/adminclient/src/main.js: Unexpected token (5:16)

3 | import App from './App';
  4 |

> 5 | ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('app'));
>       |                 ^
>       at Parser.raise (/Users/logurvp/Documents/GitHub/local/populardoctor_webapi/adminclient/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:4051:15)

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "sendotp": "^1.2.9"
  },
```

webpackconfig

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/main.js'],
  devtool: 'sourcemaps',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:5000'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([outputDirectory]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Could you please add the code also, because this kind of error message alone might not help to understand the issue.

Comment: Could you delete node_modules folder and do an npm install and try running it?

Comment: It caused due to `babel-loader` version issue.
Now fixed

Comment: Thanks @KiranMathewMohan for the response